# Jest React Redux Testing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, jest-fetch-mock

I am new to redux and I want to know how to test Actions and Reducers.

I have attached a copy of both the files and would like anyone to help with a common pattern which I can use.

I am using Jest for unit testing.

URL is http://localhost:30001.

Just want to know how the testing can be done and how I can use fetch in my test cases and what can I put as my expected result.

Actions page

```
import {
  REQUEST_CHARITIES,
  REQUEST_PAYMENT,
  SHOW_DONATION_AMOUNT_LIST,
  UPDATE_DONATION_AMOUNT_LIST,
  URL,
  PAY_NOW,
  UPDATE_MESSAGE,
  UPDATE_TOTAL_DONATE
} from './const';

//get list of all the charities
export function requestCharitiesList() {
  const request = fetch(`${URL}/charities`, {
      method: 'GET'
  }).then(response => response.json())
  return {
      type: REQUEST_CHARITIES,
      payload: request
  }
}

//get list of all payment amount
export function requestDonationAmount() {
  return {
      type: REQUEST_PAYMENT,
      payload: [{
              "id": 0,
              "price": 10
          },
          {
              "id": 1,
              "price": 20
          },
          {
              "id": 2,
              "price": 50
          },
          {
              "id": 3,
              "price": 100
          },
          {
              "id": 4,
              "price": 500
          },
      ]
  }
}

//get the total count of charities and update the payment options list visibility
export function showDonationList() {
  const paymentOptionsShow = []
  const request = fetch(`${URL}/charities`, {
      method: 'GET'
  }).then( response =>  response.json())
  request.then(function(result) {
    if(result.length >= 1){
      let arrayLength = result.length

      for( var i = 0 ; i < arrayLength ; i++ ) {
        paymentOptionsShow.push({active: false });
      }  
    }
 })

  return {
      type: SHOW_DONATION_AMOUNT_LIST,
      payload: paymentOptionsShow
  }
}

//to show and hide the payment options for each card
export function updateDonationList(list,id){
  return {
    type: UPDATE_DONATION_AMOUNT_LIST,
    payload: {
        "list": list,
        "id": id
        }
  }
}


//post the current paid amount
export function payNow(id, amount, currency) {
  const request = fetch(`${URL}/payments`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: `{ "charitiesId": ${id}, "amount": ${amount}, "currency": "${currency}" }`
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  return {
    type: PAY_NOW,
    payload: request
  }
}

//show thank you message
export function updateMessage(message) {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_MESSAGE,
    message: message
  }
}

//get the total number of payments made
export function summaryTotal() {
  const request = fetch(`${URL}/payments`,
    { method: 'GET' }).then(response => response.json())
  return {
    type: UPDATE_TOTAL_DONATE,
    payload: request
  }
}
```

One of my Reducers

```
import {
  REQUEST_CHARITIES
} from '../actions/const'

export default function (state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST_CHARITIES:
      return action.payload
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Reducers are just functions, so if you are familiar with testing it is the same principle. Your reducers are already exported so, therefore, can be imported and used in a test file. Run the functions inside your test cases and pass different state and action objects, then you can expect the results you expect based on these parameters.

Comment: got your point. I will try out the solution you have suggested. I have attached a small code of my actions test  if you dont mind can u have a look and let me know if everything is correct
Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 0):

So, this is a simple example of how my comment could work. Understand?

```
describe('Test case', () => {

  it('should return a new state', () => {
    const myReducer = nameOfReducer( { state }, { action } );

    expect(myReducer).toEqual({ state });
  });
});
```

Comment: it('`requestDonationAmount` to check the donation amounts', () => {
    let expectedResult =  { 
      type: all.REQUEST_PAYMENT,
      payload: 
              [ { id: 0, price: 10 },
                { id: 1, price: 20 },
                { id: 2, price: 50 },
                { id: 3, price: 100 },
                { id: 4, price: 500 } ] }   
      expect(requestDonationAmount()).toEqual(expectedResult)
    
  })

Comment: it('`requestCharitiesList` to check the length', () => {
   
    requestCharitiesList().payload.then(res => {
      expect(res.length).toEqual(5)
    })
  })

Comment: I thought you were testing the reducer?

Comment: I'm testing both actions and reducers

Comment: Like any function, you have to think what values do I give it and what do I expect in return. Call the functions with mocked values and expect your result.